# Linker: Moving all functions but two to a specific memory region

Tags: c, linker, binutils, linker-scripts

I am working on firmware for a PIC32MX microcontroller.  The program memory should be split into three segments:

- Section 1: interrupt service routine and main function (`startup_region`)
- Section 2: 50% of remaining program memory (`program1`)
- Section 3: 50% of remaining program memory (`program2`)

The firmware is only stored in either Section 2 or 3.  The other is reserved for future updates.  As such the active region can safely override the other to store the update.  A config bit is flipped and the main() function of Section 0 now jumps to the other program on reboot.

As such I need the linker to put all functions except `isr` and `main` into Section 1 and everything else into Section 2.  Section 3 must be left completely empty, as it may be overridden in the future.

I already tried to achieve this by modifying the default linker script, however I had no success.

linkerscript.ld:

```
/* [...] */
INCLUDE procdefs.gld
/* [...] */
SECTIONS
{
  /* [...] */
  .text :
  {
    /* isr() and main() should be at the very first locations in program memory */
    *(.text.isr)
    *(.text.main)
    /* [...] */
    . = ALIGN(4) ;
  } >kseg0_program_mem

  .program1 :
  {
    *(*.text)
  } >program1

  /* [...] */
}
```

procdefs.gld:

```
/* [...] */
MEMORY
{
  kseg0_program_mem     (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x9D000000, LENGTH = 0x10000
  startup_region        (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x9D000000, LENGTH = 0x01000
  program1              (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x9D002000, LENGTH = 0x07000
  program2              (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x9D009000, LENGTH = 0x07000
  kseg0_boot_mem              : ORIGIN = 0x9FC00490, LENGTH = 0x970
  /* [...] */
}
/* [...] */
```

This results in the following:

`isr()` and `main()` are where they are supposed to be (`0x9D00000` is the `KSEG0` virtual address of the beginning of the program flash)

```
.text           0x9d000000       0x94
 *(.text.isr)
 .text.isr      0x9d000000       0x60 build/default/production/main.o
                0x9d000000                isr
 *(.text.main)
 .text.main     0x9d000060       0x34 build/default/production/main.o
                0x9d000060                main
```

The `program1` region is correctly placed and most object files are listed correctly (notice however, that `main.o` is listed again -- it was already used).

```
.program1       0x9d002000      0xc44
 *(*.text)
 .text          0x9d002000        0x0 /opt/microchip/xc32/v2.10/bin/bin/../../lib/gcc/pic32mx/4.8.3/../../../../pic32mx/lib/./proc/32MX330F064H/crt0_mips32r2.o
 .text          0x9d002000        0x0 /opt/microchip/xc32/v2.10/bin/bin/../../lib/gcc/pic32mx/4.8.3/../../../../pic32mx/lib/debug-exception-return.o
 .text          0x9d002000        0x0 build/default/production/main.o
 .text          0x9d002000        0x0 build/default/production/commands.o
 /* [...] */
 .text          0x9d002000        0x0 build/default/production/micro-ecc/uECC.o
```

However, some function are located outside of this region:

```
.text.uECC_verify
                0x9d000b04      0x7c0
 .text.uECC_verify
                0x9d000b04      0x7c0 build/default/production/micro-ecc/uECC.o
                0x9d000b04                uECC_verify

.text.vli_mmod_fast_secp256r1
                0x9d0012c4      0x520
 .text.vli_mmod_fast_secp256r1
                0x9d0012c4      0x520 build/default/production/micro-ecc/uECC.o
```

I do not understand why this happens.

My questions are:

- How can I enforce the linker to put all functions (except `main` and `isr`) into `program1`.
- How can I prohibit the linker to put anything into `program2`, so that it remains free.

I am compiling the software with the `-ffunction-segments` switch, so that each function gets its own segment.

The original linkerscript also contains this suspicious looking comment:

```
/* Code Sections - Note that input sections *(.text) and *(.text.*)
   are not mapped here. Starting in C32 v2.00, the best-fit allocator
   locates them, so that .text may flow around absolute sections
   as needed.
*/
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `*(.text.*)` in the .program1 section?

Comment: You are correct!  It works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object file main.o is not the same as the function’s memory segment `.tex.main`. If this object file produces some other text segments they will be placed elsewhere. This is what you see in your map file.

As @Ctx mentioned the syntax of your text segment is wrong instead of `*(*.text)` it should be

```
  .program1 :
  {
    *(.text*)
  } >program1
```

This way all other text segments will be properly placed in the `program1` memory.